# Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'parentNode' of null

Tags: extjs

Here is my code:

```
 drop: function (node, data, dropRec, dropPosition) {
                Ext.Ajax.request({
                    url: 'ajax_trees.php',
                    params:{
                        id: data.records[0].get('Id'),
                        action: "changeParent",
                        newParentId: dropRec.data.Id
                    }
                });

                structureStore.reload();
            }
```

After ajax request finishes I reload the store and get Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'parentNode' of null and after that everything crashes. Anyone has idea how to fix this error?

Answer (score 0):

you don't reload your store after ajax request. The ajax request is an asynchronous work so if you want someting to do after ajax response, use success callback. That is the example;

```
Ext.Ajax.request({
    url: 'ajax_trees.php',
    params:{
            id: data.records[0].get('Id'),
            action: "changeParent",
            newParentId: dropRec.data.Id
          }
    success : function(response) {
            structureStore.reload();
          }
```